# GWT Editor - assignable to the raw Editor type, but a type parameterization is required

Tags: gwt, editor

I'm trying to use the editor framework in GWT so that I can have multiple editors editing the same bean (each editor edits a disjoint subset of fields).

Here's roughly what I have:

```java
class EventEditor implements Editor<MajorEvent> {

    // Dispatch to a sub editor. 
    // Later there will be multiple such sub editors with different types,
    // but all implementing Editor<MajorEvent>.

    @Path("")
    public GenSubEditor genSubEditor() {
        return genPresenter.getView().getSubEditor();
    }
}

public class GenSubEditor implements Editor<MajorEvent> {

    Editor<String> nameEditor() {
        return endDate;
    }
}
```

And here's the error the GWT compiler gives me:

`` The type `GenSubEditor` is assignable to the raw Editor type, but a type parameterization is required. ``

If I replace `GenSubEditor` by `Editor<MajorEvent>` in the `genSubEditor` method, the compiler doesn't complain. But then it seems that the driver generator doesn't parse my sub editor and the `nameEditor` is never found. So that's not a solution, or it means that I did something else wrong.

Hope someone can help. I did not provide a SSCCE because I don't actually know how to create a stub gwt presenter/view, but if someone tells me how to do it, I'd be glad to.

Comment: `nameEditor` is suspicious here: the generator can't do much things from an `Editor<String>`. You probably want a `LeafValueEditor<String>` or any subtype of `Editor<String>` that could have sub-editors (with `@Path("")`). That won't solve your issue though I'm afraid.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I replaced the return types with concrete types, but it doesn't solve the problem. Could it be that I need a driver interface for all my sub editors too ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is a GWT bug.
The GWT compiler won't read generics types of non-static inner classes.
In this case, it knows that `GenSubEditor` implements `Editor`, but fails to read its `MajorEvent` parameter type.

Try making `GenSubEditor` a `static` class.
Remember to remove all references to the instance of the outer class, if you use any.

I'll try to submit a bug report about this issue.